# TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics

I am creating a Turtle program which will draw a Christmas Tree and some baubles. I want the baubles to have random colors and go to random points on the Christmas Tree. This is my code:

```
turtle.goto(random.randint(1,8)),(random.randint(1,8))
```

However when I run the program, this error appears:

> TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not int

How do I fix this?

Comment: there are problems with your parenthesis in `goto` and `randint()`

Comment: can you show the definition of your function `goto` ?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about turtle, but my best guess is that there is issue with your parenthesis:

```
turtle.goto(random.randint(1,8)),(random.randint(1,8))
#   Extra closing parenthesis  ^,^ extra opening
```

Change it to:

```
turtle.goto(random.randint(1,8), random.randint(1,8))
```

Answer (score 2):

`goto` takes an `x` and an optional `y` `turtle.goto(x, y=None)`

if we had

```
x = random.randint(1,8)
y = random.randint(1,8)
```

we could do

```
turtle.goto(x, y)
```

Or in one go, with some spaces for readability and extra chance of spotting mistakes, with as few braces as possible

```
turtle.goto( random.randint(1,8), random.randint(1,8) )
```

You don't need the extra paraens around the values you give to `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this response is too late and if useful. I think you have two extra parentheses in the code. Just remove them as shown below. It shall work for you.

```
turtle.goto(random.randint(1,8),random.randint(1,8))
```